# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {58968145-CF05-4341-995F-2EE093F6ABA3} failed

Tags: c#, interop, console-application, dsofile

I am running a c# application and I am using DSOFile dll. This DLL is referenced in the project. I am able to run the exe in my development machine. 
But when I run the exe in another machine, I am getting

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {58968145-CF05-4341-995F-2EE093F6ABA3} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Not sure why I am getting this. Have googled and set the Platform target to x86
But still I am getting this issue. Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm guessing the COM library is not registered on the other computer.  Try doing a `regsvr32.exe DSOFile.dll` from the command-line with admin rights on the target system

Comment: Thanks a lot MickyD. In this scenario, do I need to register this COM library in each of the machines where exe is running?

Comment: Thanks MickyD. I dont remember doing this in my Dev machine. This makes me wondering is there something else I am missing

Comment: Ah the 'ol' "It works on my machine argument" ;)   Without knowing what the DSOFile library does, it's quite possible it was registered on your box without you being aware. Perhaps some installer?  Anyway check out my suggestion below.

Answer (score 3):

---

This is a summary of our conversation that took place beneath the question.

---

> 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

That means COM object you are trying to instantiate is a class that is not COM registered.  COM uses the registry to maintain class registrations.

Try doing a **regsvr32.exe DSOFile.dll** from the command-line with admin rights on the target system.

> I dont remember doing this in my Dev machine. This makes me wondering is there something else I am missing

Yes, try the following check:

### Quick check

I recommend using Microsoft's free tool *OleView* (normally installed with Visual Studio) to check all things COM but in the event you don't have it, open up RegEdit and see if the following key exists:

```
HKCR\CLSID\{58968145-CF05-4341-995F-2EE093F6ABA3}
```

If it's not present on the target machine, then DSOFile is not registered.

If it is there, expand the above key and you should see a child key called **InprocServer32**.  The **(Default)** value for this key will be the path to the DLL, in this case DSOFile.dll.

### More

If you want to use OleView, take a look in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\

Actual location may vary based on version of Visual Studio or Windows SDKs installed I suspect.

Once running, look in **Automation Objects** for your class.

[image]

Failing that, look in **All Objects**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Micky. I will follow your instructions. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Adding to this since I just had an issue:

If you're on a 64-bit system, DSOFile.dll doesn't work. You will need to run "regsvr32.exe DSOFile_x64.dll"for the 64-bit version.