# Extract embedded table from doc(x) file .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, streamreader

As I understand it - the shortest way is to convert file to XML. That would then allow to find the table by tag.

```
var fileinfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\Users\a1oleg\Desktop\myFile.docx");                        

XDocument xml = null;
using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(fileinfo.FullName)
{                
    xml = XDocument.Load(oReader);
}
```

The error is:

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'

Comment: docx is a zipped xml. So first it needs to be unzipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Documents docs = app.Documents;
Document doc = docs.Open("C:\\users\\Test.docx", ReadOnly:true);
Table tbl = doc.Tables[1];
Range rg = tbl.Range;
Cells cells = rg.Cells;
```

Comment: with Project - Properties - Build - Target Platform:
Any CPU || x64

       The error is:

       > System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Класс не зарегистрирован (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

with x86 
Drops out of the debug with no result, without reaching the breakpoint after your code.

Comment: answer to this error can be found here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284589/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-retrieving-the-com-class-factory-fo